# Xcode error running react native NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am getting the following error while running a react native project in xcode:

```
2018-07-12 14:19:13.336 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:210] 
Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x6000001d4be0> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6080002c1260>, executor: (null))
2018-07-12 14:19:13.338799+0200 pleasefix[16614:4513384] Initializing 
<RCTCxxBridge: 0x6000001d4be0> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6080002c1260>, 
executor: (null))
2018-07-12 14:19:13.444 [warn][tid:main][RCTBridge.m:119] Class 
RCTCxxModule was not exported. Did you forget to use 
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?
2018-07-12 14:19:13.444411+0200 pleasefix[16614:4513384] Class 
RCTCxxModule was not exported. Did you forget to use 
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?
2018-07-12 14:19:13.471746+0200 pleasefix[16614:4513384] -[RCTCxxBridge 
devSettings]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000001d4be0
2018-07-12 14:19:13.487811+0200 pleasefix[16614:4513384] *** Terminating 
app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '- 
[RCTCxxBridge devSettings]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
0x6000001d4be0'
```

Has anyone experienced this issue? Any ideas how to fix?